# Rails - Saving external API call to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm making a GET call to an external source (a Spree Commerce store) for getting the list of orders... the call is working fine but I need to save the order list to my rails app's db. I have no idea how to do this.

My Controller:

```
def index
  # GRAB THE URL
  url = 'https://cuytest1.herokuapp.com/api/v1/orders.json?token=982fe19b763ee46bf1ea6ca6ddf70c61f2b6571c7434c22c'
  response = HTTParty.get(url)

  # PARSE THE RESPONSE
  @orders = response.parsed_response["orders"]
end
```

My model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  include HTTParty
end
```

My view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Orders</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order["number"] %></td>
        <td><%= order["total"] %></td>
        <td><%= order["shipment_state"] %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If anyone can point me into the right direction will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is actually not a bad one. But it seems, you didn't do your homework. Make sure you get a basic understanding how ActiveRecord works with your model. This should be clear after doing the Getting Started Tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Create a new Orders table w/ a `details` column of JSON type
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
     t.json :details
    end
  end
end

# And a corresponding model
class Order < ApplicationRecord
end

# Then when you're fetching those orders:
Order.new(details: fetched_order_record)

# That might look something like this in practice:
client = Spree::Client.new(...)
orders = client.orders.parsed_response
orders.each do |order_hash|
  Order.create! details: order_hash
end

# Later when you load from the database
order = Order.first
order.details['total']
```

Comment: Passersby: downvotes are from users who are upset the question was answered, not that it's low quality.

Comment: Thanks @coreyward...i'm still trying to figure out your solution. I'm clearly a beginner